# WebRTC Scalable-Broadcast with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webrtc, live-streaming

I'm looking for a system to asp.net for live webcam video streaming... after two weeks looking for this on google, I found several very interesting projects, but many of them use flash, and I do not want to use flash to watch the video because the site will have to open the phone also...
So, Then one of the projects that pleased me most was the WebRTC, especially this demo ( https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Scalable-Broadcast/ ( source code: https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Scalable-Broadcast )), the problem is that this project is written in node.js, and I do like to use it with my ASP.NET page.

how can I do to use this system on my site?

My site will have a one-to-many connection, and this was the only project I found that does that, I analyzed the use of the peerjs for this, but it does not work for this.
I have looked to Janus project, but can not find a way to use it in my asp.net page.

Comment: Install nodejs on port 9001. It will run socket.io on port 9001. Now your ASP.NET page (on port 80/443) can use port 9001 as following: `io.connect('https://domain.com:9001')`. You can even install socket.io on a separate server e.g. heroku and your ASP.NET can use socket.io from hereoku by setting single line as explained above.